# Differences between hadoop jar and yarn -jar

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, command, hadoop-yarn

what's the difference between run a jar file with commands "hadoop jar " and "yarn -jar " ?

I've used the "hadoop jar" command on my MAC successfully but I want be sure that the execution is being correct and parallel on my four cores.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Are you worried that `hadoop jar` isn't properly distributing your computation, or that `yarn jar` might not?

Comment: @climbage yes I'm worried for the reason above and also: what changes between the two commands since they do the same thing (maybe :)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short Answer**

They are probably identical for you, **but** even if they aren't, they should both utilize your cluster to the best of its ability.

---

**Longer Answer**

The `/usr/bin/yarn` script sets up the execution environment so that all of the yarn commands can be run.  The `/usr/bin/hadoop` script isn't quite as concerned about yarn specific functionality.  However, if you have your cluster set up to use yarn as the default implementation of mapreduce (MRv2), then `hadoop jar` will probably act the same as `yarn jar` for a mapreduce job.

Either way you're probably fine, but you can always check the resource manager  (or job tracker) web interface to see how your job is distributed across the cluster (whether it's a single node cluster or not)